# For loop working and returning a result but then stopping and returning- TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

I have a node server set up that makes an api request and gets some json data.  I'm trying to extract some of that data into an array and it seems to be working when I send the result to the console but then the program stops and gives me an error.  Here is my code.

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  var myArray = [];
  bodies = JSON.parse(body);
  let tag = '';
  let bond = '';
  let members = '';
  for(var i = 0; i <= bodies.memberCount; i++){

    let bond = bodies.members[i];
    let smoke = bond.tag;
    if(smoke === "undefined"){
      return;
    }else{

      console.log(smoke);
    }
  }
});

the output in the console is this- 

YYVPJ0G
2PJP89J2Q
9G8Y8022
JC90J0R
9LLYVQVQ
QV2R90V
JC9JVV
20RLC0QY
28LP0P8CG
2QYLGG9GY
2JRQQYQQJ
9YJVV0GJ
2RVP8U9
9VYG0VGQ
C2PGPYC
8CJ9CGG2
YGV0CRL
2VUV22VQY
R8G82YG
PPJUYQJ
28VYV2QJG
YC9LR0G9
8088RCYG
2JUJR2QVY
2YRPUC2Q
GJ0QP90
UGU9LR8
GJQRVC8C
UVVVJ80Q
LURGY8JV
2C9UJRP82
20J9VYVC0
82GUQLYRL
L2PCUYP
2CQUYPJRU
PYU98GU9
9QR2CCCLV
PP9V2P0
CGYLUG
8QLPJRYC2
Y2GYCLU
LQJ0QQ8
P2Y08LLP
P0RUVLG82
/home/phil/ClashApp/requests.js:34
let smoke = bond.tag;
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined
    at Request._callback (/home/phil/ClashApp/requests.js:34:18)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:148:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:896:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> 
    (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/index.js:847:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
```

it gives all the results I want but stops the program before I can push them all the myArray....

Comment: Should probably be `i < bodies.memberCount` instead of `<=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the numbering of arrays starts from zero, and the length is the number of elements in array so the last index is not the length of the array, but the length - 1.

So you need to replace `i <= bodies.memberCount` to `i < bodies.memberCount`

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  var myArray = [];
  bodies = JSON.parse(body);
  let tag = '';
  let bond = '';
  let members = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < bodies.memberCount; i++){ 
     let bond = bodies.members[i];
     let smoke = bond.tag;
     if(smoke === "undefined"){
       return;
     }else{
        console.log(smoke);
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is almost certainly the correct answer, but it's helpful to include a clear explanation of what you changed and why (not just in a code comment).

Comment: @pointy also I don't see any sense in answering typos over and over ...

Comment: @JonasWilms well I agree with that of course, but an answer is an answer and it might as well be done right.

Comment: Hi everyone.  All I ended up changing was what Nikita Umnov suggested,  i < bodies.memberCount, instead of, i <= bodies.memberCount.  Also dropped the variables: tag, bond and members.  I had only added those as I went trying to figure out what I had done wrong, because the variables kept coming back undefined.   I really appreciate all the help!  First time poster here!

Answer (score 2):

"bond" does not contains the "tag" key on a specific bodies.members[index] index.

add a check something like this.

```
if(bond.tag !== undefined)
   smoke =  bond.tag
```